# Laravel: keep login (authenticated status) manually

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

My website has multiple authentications *for different purposes*. Authorization *is not* proper here because for each kind of authentication different data required, so for each kind of authentication separate database tables uses.

E. g. all that **admins** are need is email and password: email uses as ID for authentication. Now, to look theirs sites in development, which is currently a part of my own site, **customers** needs also order ID, customer's name, website name, and alias data. For example:

- Future website domain: `stivenson-gym.com`
- Website name: Stevenson's gym
- Order ID: StivensonGym
- Customer: Michael Stivenson
- Subwebsite top page's url: `www.webmaster-example.com/orders/stivenson-gym/index.html`
- This order's alias (part of above url): `stivenson-gym`

Unlike the authentication of admins, here is **Order ID** (not customer's name) uses for signing in.

I already realized:

- Manual OrderID and password checking
- Routing with dynamic alias building for each order id.

Now I need to keep customer logging in during he browses his website.

Why `Auth::attempt(['orderID' => $orderID, 'password' => $password])` will not use? Because this method refers to `Users` table, but I need `Orders` table. I can't change globally table for `Auth` because **admins** needs the different table for authentication.

In the theory, the solution will be:

- Write in the session that certain customer currently browses he's subwebsite.
- When the customer change the internal page of he's subwebsite, first it's required to check the above recording in the session.
- When the customer leaves his subsite - clear the section.

I will add my current code without authorization:

```
class LoginToSitesInDevelopmentZoneController extends Controller {

  const SITE_IN_DEVELOPMENT_TABLE_NAME = 'site_in_dev';

      const ORDER_ID_FIELD_NAME = 'order_id';
      const PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME = 'password';
      const SITENAME_FIELD_NAME = 'sitename';
      const CUSTOMER_NAME_FIELD_NAME = 'customer_name';
      const ALIAS_FIELD_NAME = 'alias';

  public function login(Request $request) {

    $inputtedOrderId = $request->input('order_id');       // from login form

    // manual check is this order exists
    $orderIdInDB = DB::table(self::SITE_IN_DEVELOPMENT_TABLE_NAME)
            ->where(self::ORDER_ID_FIELD_NAME, $inputtedOrderId)->first();

    if (is_null($orderIdInDB)) {
       return Redirect::route('loginToSitesInDevelopmentZonePage')->withErrors(['wrongOrderId' => true])->withInput();
    }

    // from login form       
    $inputtedPassword = $request->input('password');

    // manual check the order id and password compilance
    $bcryptedPasswordFromDB = DB::table(self::SITE_IN_DEVELOPMENT_TABLE_NAME)
            ->where(self::ORDER_ID_FIELD_NAME, $inputtedOrderId)->value(self::PASSWORD_FIELD_NAME);

    if (!Hash::check($inputtedPassword,$bcryptedPasswordFromDB)) {
        return Redirect::route('loginToSitesInDevelopmentZonePage')->withErrors(['wrongPassword' => true]);
    }


    // get respective alias
    $alias = DB::table(self::SITE_IN_DEVELOPMENT_TABLE_NAME)
            ->where(self::ORDER_ID_FIELD_NAME, $inputtedOrderId)->value(self::ALIAS_FIELD_NAME);

    // here I need to provide acess of the customer to all pages above 'sites_in_development_zone/'.$alias

    return redirect('sites_in_development_zone/'.$alias.'/index.html');

  }
}
```

Thanks in advance for any help.