# Laravel: understanding the "credentials" method mechanism

Tags: php, laravel

I need the custom authentication, namely:

- Custom model and DB table for `LoginController` (solved)
- "Order ID" instead of email for authentication (solved)

Because I do not understand the `credentials` method mechanism, I get the error:

```
Type error: Argument 1 passed to Illuminate\Auth\EloquentUserProvider::validateCredentials() 
must be an instance of Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable,  
instance of App\Order given, called in C:\OpenServer\domains\sites-in-development.loc\vendor\laravel\framework\src\Illuminate\Auth\SessionGuard.php on line
```

[image]

```
<?php

class LoginController extends Controller {

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    protected $redirectTo; 
    protected $orderAlias;

    protected $loginView;

    /*
        Here I set the order ID as "username". I don't like this method,
        because it causes the confusion ($username is actually order ID),
        but don't know the other way yet.
        REF is just the class with array contains the string values to avoid hardcoding
    */
    protected $username = REF::tables['orders']['fieldNames']['orderId'];


    public function __construct() {

        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
        $this->loginView = '00_top';

    }


    public function showLoginForm() {
        // Work properly
    }


    public function login(Request $request) {

        if ($this->hasTooManyLoginAttempts($request)) {

            $this->fireLockoutEvent($request);
            return $this->sendLockoutResponse($request);
        }


        // manual validation (work properly)
        // getting $orderAlias from DB

        $redirectTo = '/'.$orderAlias;

        if ($this->attemptLogin($request)) {
            return $this->sendLoginResponse($request); // to "credentials"... 
        }

        $this->incrementLoginAttempts($request);

        return $this->sendFailedLoginResponse($request);

    }

    protected function credentials(Request $request) {

        // here is error
        return $request->only(REF::forms['loginToOrder']['fieldNames']['orderID'], 
                REF::forms['loginToOrder']['fieldNames']['password']);
    }
}
```

Comment: you are trying to login an 'order' as a 'user'?

Comment: @lagbox, what do you mean? I login using 'orders' table, 'order ID' instead of 'email' to authenticate, and I deleted 'users' table. I set the 'order ID' as `$username` - it's required for authentication methods (almost all methods of  `AuthenticatesUsers` works with email as ID to logging in). Really I want fully manual authentication, but I don't know how to keep logging in when redirect (I was consider it in [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47425457/laravel-keep-login-authenticated-status-manually) question, but still no answers).

Answer (score 0):

The model you want to use has to implement the `Authenticatable` interface/contract.

[Laravel - Docs - Authentication - The Authenticatable Contract](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/authentication#the-authenticatable-contract)

Comment: Thank you for the answer. I am sorry, but there is no example for `Interface Authenticatable`, so I do not understand how to use it. Could you add the example of using `interface Authenticatable` for authentication with `$orderID` instead of email please?